# C++ ofstream not creating and writing to file on subsequent runs of the program

Tags: c++, fstream, file-handling, ofstream

```
#include <iostream>

#define LOGFATAL(msg) log(0, msg)

std::ofstream *logst = NULL;

void log(int sev, char *msg)
{   if (logst == NULL) {
        logst = new std::ofstream();
        logst->open("filea.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
        *logst << "Logger started." << std::endl;
    }

    std::ofstream &_log = *logst;
    _log << msg << std::endl;
    _log.flush();
}

int main()
{   LOGFATAL("Log msg1.");
    LOGFATAL("Log msg2.");
    LOGFATAL("Log msg3.");

    logst->close();
    delete logst;
}
```

I am opening a file for logging the very first time I log and continue to keep it open until the end of program.

Since I use the `flush()` operation after every log invocation, I expect to see my messages printed close to immediately. BUT THIS DID NOT HAPPEN. WHY?

Currently, I kill my program using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> before it finishes (Don't ask me why). On subsequent runs of the program I don't even see the log file getting created and even if it already exists I don't see any logs getting added. Since I don't let the `close()` execute, does the file descriptor get leaked and prevent future `open()` from new programs to fail?

I am running it on a RHEL 7.2 and I assume most new OS's handle these days even if `close()` isn't called accidentally. Considering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is the only way to stop my program currently, what can I do to make my program to log correctly every time it is started?

Is there a way from the system shell to check if there are any leaked file descriptors to my log file?

Comment: How are you making the determination your messages are *not* being printed "close to immediately" ? Regarding killing your process, once it's gone, so are all it's open file streams, so you shouldn't be "leaking" *anything*. The process is *gone*. That said, are you *sure* you're using the [appropriate flags for your `open` call](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open) ?

Comment: I am tailing the log file and don't see logs for a while after I hit flush() in gdb. But this is not the most worrying problem. Not opening and writing at all on subsequent runs of the program is the bigger issue.

I set the std::ios::out and std::ios::app modes. Should I be doing anything else?

Comment: Also as a side note, logging function should `open, log and close the file` on every log printed in project in order to capture the flow/activity in a better way.

Comment: @sameerkn woudln't that be inefficient? Every log would incur the cost of a open and close system call.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting `std::endl` will itself flush the data. It works for me even if `_log.flush();` is commented.

*"I expect to see my messages printed close to immediately"*. If you are using `vim` then you need to close and reopen the file. So, use `tail -F filea.txt` to see the output immediately if data gets written to file.

Comment: But I don't see anything printed at all in the subsequent runs of the program. I put in the is_open() check and I see that the open() is not even opening the file.

Comment: @siri, Since `fstream::open()` does not return anything, so in this case, would suggest that you use `fopen` to open the file in `a+` mode and check error if any via `errno variable`.

Comment: @siri Just for kicks, use `std::ios::out | std::ios::app | std::ios::ate` for your open flags. And I know you're using RHEL, but what toolchain?

Comment: @WhozCraig gcc 4.8

Answer (score 0):

Take the following steps to validate some assumptions:

1.) Open your file as `std::fstream` instead. After writing the first log message, reset the file pointer to the beginning and read the contents of the file. **You should be getting your log message from the open file.** If not, then you probably have a memory corruption.

2.) After writing the first log message, open the file with an `std::ifstream` and read its contents. **You should be getting your log message from the `std::ifstream`.** If not, then there is probably another process interfering with your file.

**Note:** The OS takes some time to make file changes visible to other processes. Under high load I have observed delays of several 100 ms, e.g. until the message shows up in `tail -f`.